# Are there any Core Heating Technology (CHT) nozzles available for a stock Ender 3 V2 hotend?

Tags: nozzle, speed, e3d-v6, cht, mk8

I already switched my standard 0.4 mm nozzle to a standard 0.6 mm nozzle with a huge printing time reduction without losing much detail. I also would like to try using Core Heating Technology (CHT) 0.6 mm nozzle instead, to be able to increase printing speeds and reduce printing time even more.

[CNC Kitchen](https://www.cnckitchen.com/blog/bondtech-cht-high-flow-nozzle-reviewed) tested the performance with the following results:

[image: Extrusion Performance 0.6 mm V6 vs CHT nozzle vs Volcano]

I found some E3DV6 CHT nozzles, do they fit on a stock Ender 3 V2 hotend or do I need a specific E3D hotend for that? Or since I don't want to upgrade my hotend, are there MK8 CHT nozzles, or are the sizes the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the functional difference between an e3D-Style nozzle, Makerbot MK8 and M6 Chinesium Nozzles?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/9912/what-is-the-functional-difference-between-an-e3d-style-nozzle-makerbot-mk8-and)

Comment: @Trish Not really but it's certainly helpful. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: The answer from there is "You can always use an e3D v3 CHT to replace a Makerbot Mk6-8 or Creality Mk8,, it will fit in the stock ender3, just have longer threads. Adjust bed as needed."

Comment: Doesn't a longer thread affect the compatibility with BLtouch, since the height changes too and the probe length? That question you refered to is more about the 'functional differences of nozzle models' while this one is more about availability and compatibility, specifically for CHT. I think it's somewhat similar but asked and answered from a different perspective and perhaps with a different goal in mind.

Comment: The BL Touch  can be readjusted to match the needed height, and indeed should be done whenever you swap nozzles.

Comment: The longer thread doesn't impose on the BLTouch, the overall length will. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the main question, yes there are, the typical Chinese market places are flooded with these nozzles nowadays, these are less well manufactured than the original BondTech CHT MK8 (coated) nozzles you can find in decent 3D printer shops.

Simply search for "CHT MK8 nozzle" and you get a list to order from in various sizes, including the requested 0.6 mm.

*Image of a typical cloned MK8 CHT nozzle:*

[image]

*Image of an original E3D v6 CHT nozzle:*

[image]

Do note the quality differences, the original are superior machines apposed to the clones, look at the pattern of the inner 3 bore holes, the original is much closer together so that the filament flows directly into the 3 holes (almost 1 big hole in fact) whereas for the clones the 3 bore holes are apart causing the filament to hit a wall (center piece) and needs to be diverted to the outer 3 holes.

> ... E3DV6 CHT nozzles, do they fit on a stock Ender 3 V2 hotend or do I need a specific E3D hotend...

Looking at the dimensions below, you see that the threads are identical (both M6x1), but the overall length is 0.5 mm shorter for the E3D v6, so this should match. [This reference](https://filament2print.com/gb/blog/25_compatibility-nozzle-v6-mk8-volcano.html) tells us that the nozzles are interchangeable:

> For the [Creality] MK8 nozzle, it *[red. i.e. the E3D v6 nozzle]* will be compatible with 3D printers that use [Creality] MK8 hotends. [Creality] MK8 nozzles are incompatible with the V6 ecosystem.

The E3D v6 will work on the MK8 because they are longer from the threads to the base of the hexagonal nut, therefore MK8 will not work in an E3D v6 hotend, they are too short. You cannot screw in the MK8 far enough into E3D v6 far enough, the base of the hexagonal nut will touch the heater block and leaves a space between the nozzle and the heat break. If these aren't sufficiently tightened together, the heat block may leak and the cavity is detrimental for retraction performance.

---

*Information on the dimension of the different nozzles*

Creality MK8 dimensions:
[image]

E3D v6 dimensions:
[image]

Comment: So it needs to be a specific MK8 version, not the ED3V6 version in order to fit a stock Ender 3 V2?

Comment: Yes and no. Do note that MK8 doesn't say much, there are also (older) nozzles known as MK8 that have a smaller hexagonal diameter. You can order the v6 nozzles to fit your hotend, the genuine CHT nozzles are pretty good. I've updated the answer for you. I hope you understand that you should consider to avoid asking multiple questions in one question. Where I thought that the question was more on availability, it seems more a question of can I use a different nozzle in my hotend? But, keep the questions coming!

Comment: CHT is patented. Import could be patent infringement

Comment: The difference is more than 0.5 mm. In addition to the thread being slightly longer (I think it's 1.0 not 0.5 mm, looking at those drawings), there's (looks like 1.5 mm) additional clearance between the end of the thread and the back of the nozzle head. This is why MK8 nozzles don't work on V6 hotends - the back of the nozzle head will bottom out against the block before the intended mating surface hits the heatbreak.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE updating an old answer for that...

Comment: @Trish while the patent itself is a whole other subject: 'The US patent for CHT was seemingly rejected in the US, while E3D opposes the patent in Europe.' - all3dp.com/4/bondtech-cht-e3d-revo-heatcore-clash-on-cht-patent. Although I feel like the original maker should be supported for this, this part does contain a second part that needs to be inserted. Perhaps that's different in patent law too. I think at best it's patent pending currently.

Comment: @BobOrtiz Do note the quality differences, the original are superior aposed to the clones, look at the pattern of the inner 3 bore holes, the original is much closer together so that the filament flows directly into the 3 (almost 1 big) holes whereas for the clones the 3 bore holes are apart causing the filament to hit a wall (center piece) and needs to be diverted to the outer 3 holes. Buying original would be my advice, it is worth the expenses.

Answer (score 1):

[Creality style "MK8" hotends (including the Ender 3's) can use "MK8" **or** e3D V6 nozzles.](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/9912/what-is-the-functional-difference-between-an-e3d-style-nozzle-makerbot-mk8-and/9913#9913)

Bondtech sells genuine CHT in both Creality MK8 and e3D V6 forms. If you prefer matching what your machine has exactly, you can buy that, but it will only work on the Creality-style "MK8" hotends, not anything else. If you buy the e3D V6 version, it will work on your Ender's Creality MK8 hotend and any hotend that's compatible with e3D V6 nozzles.

I've always bought the e3D V6 version for my Ender and it's worked fine.

Comment: @Trish: OK I've edited to clarify. Does that help?

Comment: almost, missed a few E3Ds^^

Comment: @Trish: I left out E3D there because "V6" is often used generically in the industry as a nozzle standard by parties who don't want to deal with trademark issues for putting E3D's name in there, but if you'd rather put it in the answer I don't really care.

Comment: the rpoblem is, there's also *other* v6s out there, and while we know *now* that it is an e3d v6, it might become forgotten in a year and refer to... some other product